# Firebase: Get list from Key Objects

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the /players.. for every instance.. with a key. how do I achieve that?
I can't find anything on it.
My Structure is like that:

[image]

I am getting the other values (date, status, time) like that.

```
 this.gamesRef = db.list('/games');
    this.allGames = this.gamesRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() 
    }));
  });

    <div *ngFor="let game of allGames | async">
        <span class="game-div-date">{{game.date}}</span>
        <span class="game-div-clock">{{game.time}}</span>
   </div>
```

(I am using Firebase with Angular2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
this.gamesRef = db.list('/games');
    this.allGames = this.gamesRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => { 
          const games;
          games.key= c.payload.key;
          games.satus = c.payload.val().status;
          games.time = c.payload.val().time;

          let players=[]
          c.payload.val().players.forEach(player=>{
            players.push(player);
          })

          games.players = players;

          return games;
    });
});
```

This will create custom data you can use

```
<div *ngFor="let game of allGames | async">
    <span class="game-div-date">{{game.date}}</span>
    <span class="game-div-clock">{{game.time}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let player of game.players">
        <span>{{player | json}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me an Error.. ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Not working: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. - also tried player.key or player.username (which is in a User) - not working

Comment: i updated the answer, if that not work you need to build a custom `pipe` to turn your result in to ngfor supported array.

Comment: There is no error any more, but also there is no data displayed. I tried to log the created Array in the console and the Array is empty. :/

Comment: Did you notice that there is a Plus behind the names? There are also values in there. I tried to reach them with player.value but not working. I just updated my Posting.

Comment: I have custom edited the data returned from firebase. I didn't try the code myself

Comment: Thank you so much! It is not working. Can't find all the values assigned with c.payload - but had not the time to test around yet.